# docker compose YAML file: Re-using variables passed to the entrypoint as arguments

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have the following `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3'


services:

  service1:
    image: same_image:latest
    command: >
      --arg1 1000
      --arg2 2000
      --arg3 whatever

  service2:
    image: another_image:latest
    command: >
      --arg1 1000
      --arg2 2000
      --arg3 something_else
      --arg4 additional_argument
```

So I'm passing `argX` arguments to the two entrypoints in the two docker containers, and values of two of those arguments (`arg1` and `arg2`) are shared.

**My question:** how can I define those two variables in such a way that I can re-use them when passing them as arguments to the entrypoints?

I tried:

```
version: '3.4'

x-common-variables: &common-variables
  arg1: 1000
  arg2: 2000
 

services:

  service1:
    image: same_image:latest
    command: >
      --arg1 *common-variables.arg1
      --arg2 *common-variables.arg2
      --arg3 whatever

  service2:
    image: another_image:latest
    command: >
      --arg1 *common-variables.arg1
      --arg2 *common-variables.arg2
      --arg3 something_else
      --arg4 additional_argument
```

but those arguments are not being "unpacked" properly by the YAML parser.

Comment: If you control the application code, using environment variables rather than (or alongside) command-line arguments is a little easier to work with in cases like these.

Comment: I do, actually. But, yea, I guess that's not always the case and I'm more interested in the "control from the level of the docker-compose.yml file" kind of solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your best option is providing `arg1` and `arg2` in the `.env` file:

**.env**

```
arg1=1000
arg2=2000
```

**docker-file.yaml**

```yaml
version: '3.4'

services:

  service1:
    image: same_image:latest
    command: >
      --arg1 $arg1
      --arg2 $arg2
      --arg3 whatever
  service2:
    image: another_image:latest
    command: >
      --arg1 $arg1
      --arg2 $arg2
      --arg3 something_else
      --arg4 additional_argument
```

With extension fields the solution would be more complex. First of all you couldn't use the shell form (i.e. string) of the command field: YAML aliases cannot be injected into string fields. You would need to use command in the list form:

```yaml
version: '3.4'

x-common-variables: 
  - &arg1 "1000"
  - &arg2 "2000"

services:

  service1:
    image: same_image:latest
    command: 
      - --arg1 
      - *arg1
      - --arg2 
      - *arg2
      - --arg3 
      - whatever

  service2:
    image: another_image:latest
    command: 
      - --arg1 
      - *arg1
      - --arg2 
      - *arg2
      - --arg3 
      - something_else
      - --arg4 
      - additional_argument
```